# Implementation of SimulTweet for twitter?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, twitter, ios5

I'm wondering if anyone has any tips on how to implement the SimulTweet function that Twittelator Neue has?

This feature allows you to send a single tweet from multiple twitter accounts at the same time.

I am keen on implementing something similar...and I"m not sure where to start.

https://img.skitch.com/20111205-ngqp8tppuprr7w4r9jig65pm2y.jpg is a screen cap of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/). It doesn't do the simultaneous tweeting, but it has all the code you need to implement it. I'm currently implementing this for a project. When it's finished I'll try to share the code somewhere.